# how to delete string between two different special characters in csv file in python

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp

data looks like this:

```
Aberrant(congenital)|artery(peripheral) ~Q27.8|cerebral Q28.3#
```

I want to delete string between ~ and |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regular expression.

Depending whether you want to keep the `~` and `|` you could do:

```
import re
re.sub('~.*?\|', '', your_string)
```

or

```
import re
re.sub('~.*?\|', '~|', your_string)
```

Comment: [Now you have two problems.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/20842/350567)

Comment: Seems like a perfectly reasonable use of regex to me. Not to you? What are the two problems now in this case?

Comment: I agree this is a valid use of regex, but it's just a little overuse. I didn't downvote, though.

Comment: thanks a lot it work

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.find()` method to find characters in a string

```
mystr = 'Aberrant(congenital)|artery(peripheral) ~Q27.8|cerebral Q28.3#'
pos1 = mystr.find('~')
pos2 = mystr.find('|', pos1)
if pos1 >= 0 and pos2 > pos1:
    newstr = mystr[0:pos1] + mystr[pos2+1:]
print(newstr)
```

Output:

```
Aberrant(congenital)|artery(peripheral) cerebral Q28.3#
```